# Error purging PostgreSQL database. Reason: ERROR: syntax error at or near "exists"Position: 15

Tags: postgresql

I am using PostgreSQL database with Tomcat Server. When I checked webpage today, it shows about mentioned alarm with following logs:

```
2018-11-05 01:06:05,628 [1AM Thread] DEBUG com.swhh.csta.d.c.k - Purging Devices
2018-11-05 01:06:05,628 [1AM Thread] WARN  com.swhh.csta.a.n - REFRESH: TSAPI service down.
2018-11-05 01:06:05,628 [1AM Thread] WARN  com.swhh.csta.a.n - REFRESH: TSAPI service down.
2018-11-05 01:06:05,628 [1AM Thread] WARN  com.swhh.csta.a.n - REFRESH: TSAPI service down.
2018-11-05 01:06:05,628 [1AM Thread] DEBUG com.swhh.cs.e.u - No lock folder to check yet
2018-11-05 01:06:05,628 [1AM Thread] INFO  com.swhh.cs.uarchive.h - Purging and checking for historic archive runs
2018-11-05 01:06:05,628 [1AM Thread] INFO  com.swhh.cs.uarchive.h - Purging archive \\ip-address\archive3\
2018-11-05 01:06:05,643 [1AM Thread] INFO  com.swhh.cs.e.au - Purging recordings (except those locked) prior to Nov 5, 2013 1:06:05 AM
2018-11-05 01:06:05,659 [1AM Thread] INFO  com.swhh.cs.e.au - Retaining 0 contacts due to locked records from before purge point.
2018-11-05 01:06:05,659 [1AM Thread] INFO  com.swhh.cs.e.au - Retaining 0 contacts due to locked records from before purge point and/or spanning the purge point.
2018-11-05 01:06:05,659 [1AM Thread] ERROR com.swhh.cs.a.p - Alarm raised err.database.purge [ERROR: syntax error at or near "exists"
  Position: 15] [null]
2018-11-05 01:06:05,659 [1AM Thread] INFO  com.swhh.cs.e.au - Daily House-keeping completed
```

Comment: Check the postgres logs, rather than the Tomcat logs.

Answer (score 1):

After checking postgres logs, I update postgres version from 8 to 9.2 and everything works now.

Comment: Postgres 8 was already unsupported, and 9.2 has been [unsupported](https://www.postgresql.org/support/versioning/) since 2017 - you should have installed a current and supported version (e.g. 10 or 11)